# copying * files in Docker to directory gives error

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /webpieces
COPY * /webpieces
WORKDIR "/webpieces"
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/webpiecesexample"]
```

When I build like so, I get the following error

```
Deans-MacBook-Pro:webpiecesexample dean$ docker build -t gcr.io/braided-topic/webpieces2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  75.56MB
Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/5 : RUN mkdir -p /webpieces
 ---> Running in bc615c0cd540
Removing intermediate container bc615c0cd540
 ---> 69a2f4530c44
Step 3/5 : COPY * /webpieces
When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /
```

When I trim the DockerFile and just build with the first two lines and then run with a basic shell to view the directories, I see the webpieces directory there

```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh gcr.io/braided-topic-266113/webpieces2
```

I can cd into webpieces and everything.  Why is the copy command not working here?

docker version here:

```
Deans-MacBook-Pro:distributions dean$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:34 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:29:19 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When using `COPY` with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory **and end with a `/`**.

Change the `COPY` line to

```
COPY * /webpieces/
```

---

> ...it seems to copy the contents of each directory instead of the directories themselves. I would prefer not to name each directory I am moving as we prefer auto-add when we make changes.

Use `.` instead of `*` and it'll preserve all the nesting.

```
COPY . /webpieces/
```

Comment: well, that got me past one issue and copies it, but it seems to copy the contents of each directory instead of the directories themselves.  I would prefer not to name each directory I am moving as we prefer auto-add when we make changes.

Comment: COPY is failing in Azure DevOps builds but not locally.  So I'm guessing this was "fixed" in new versions of docker build, but I haven't figured out when.  (Fix version would tell me what version I should be using in Azure Devops.)